# OpenGL Applying A Global Rotation to Local Euler Angles

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I am working on an Android application using OpenGL.

In a database, I store the rotation of objects using local Euler rotation, x, y, then z, but in the editor, I would like to apply a global rotation by the x, y or z global axis. I took two approaches, outlined below.

I've simplified these methods to remove irrelevant Android code.

I've tried taking the matrix approach, but the object appears to rotate in an axis not aligned with the global x, y or z after calling the method a second time. I've read somewhere that the floating point error builds up over time making the rotation matrix "numerically unstable", which I assume is what's happening in the first method.

```
// rotAxis = 0 means rotation around the X global axis
// rotAxis = 1 means rotation around the Y global axis
// rotAxis = 2 means rotation around the Z global axis
public void executeRotationWithMatrix(float rotAngle, int rotAxis){
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];

    // Matrix class is in android.opengl
    Matrix.setIdentityM(rotationMatrix, 0);

    switch (rotAxis){
        case 0:
            Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, rotAngle, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
            break;
        case 1:
            Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, rotAngle, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
            break;
        case 2:
            Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, rotAngle, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
            break;
    }

    float rotx = getLocalRotationOfObjectOnX(); // Pseudocode
    float roty = getLocalRotationOfObjectOnY(); // Pseudocode
    float rotz = getLocalRotationOfObjectOnZ(); // Pseudocode

    Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, rotx, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, roty, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, rotz, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

    Vector3f rotationVector = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(rotationMatrix);

saveLocalRotationOfObjectOnX(rotationVector.x); // Pseudocode
saveLocalRotationOfObjectOnY(rotationVector.y); // Pseudocode
saveLocalRotationOfObjectOnZ(rotationVector.z); // Pseudocode
}
```

In the second method, I tried to take the rotation quaternion approach by applying the rotations, but I get even weirder results whenever I try to use this method.

```
// rotAxis = 0 means rotation around the X global axis
// rotAxis = 1 means rotation around the Y global axis
// rotAxis = 2 means rotation around the Z global axis
public void executeRotationWithQuat(float rotAngle, int rotAxisInd){
    Quat4f rotationQuat = new Quat4f(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Quat4f tempQuat = new Quat4f(0, 0, 0, 1);

    switch (rotAxisInd){
        case 0:
            QuaternionUtil.setRotation(tempQuat, new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), rotAngle);
            break;
        case 1:
            QuaternionUtil.setRotation(tempQuat, new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), rotAngle);
            break;
        case 2:
            QuaternionUtil.setRotation(tempQuat, new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), rotAngle);
            break;
    }

    tempQuat.normalize();
    rotationQuat.mul(tempQuat);
    rotationQuat.normalize();

    float rotx = getLocalRotationOfObjectOnX(); // Pseudocode
    float roty = getLocalRotationOfObjectOnY(); // Pseudocode
    float rotz = getLocalRotationOfObjectOnZ(); // Pseudocode

    QuaternionUtil.setRotation(tempQuat, new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), rotx); tempQuat.normalize();
    rotationQuat.mul(tempQuat);
    rotationQuat.normalize();

    QuaternionUtil.setRotation(tempQuat, new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), roty); tempQuat.normalize();
    rotationQuat.mul(tempQuat);
    rotationQuat.normalize();

    QuaternionUtil.setRotation(tempQuat, new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), rotz); tempQuat.normalize();
    rotationQuat.mul(tempQuat);
    rotationQuat.normalize();

    float qw = rotationQuat.w;
    float qx = rotationQuat.x;
    float qy = rotationQuat.y;
    float qz = rotationQuat.z;

    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[]{
            1.0f - 2.0f*qy*qy - 2.0f*qz*qz, 2.0f*qx*qy - 2.0f*qz*qw, 2.0f*qx*qz + 2.0f*qy*qw, 0.0f,
            2.0f*qx*qy + 2.0f*qz*qw, 1.0f - 2.0f*qx*qx - 2.0f*qz*qz, 2.0f*qy*qz - 2.0f*qx*qw, 0.0f,
            2.0f*qx*qz - 2.0f*qy*qw, 2.0f*qy*qz + 2.0f*qx*qw, 1.0f - 2.0f*qx*qx - 2.0f*qy*qy, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    Vector3f rotationVector = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(rotationMatrix);

saveLocalRotationOfObjectOnX(rotationVector.x); // Pseudocode
saveLocalRotationOfObjectOnY(rotationVector.y); // Pseudocode
saveLocalRotationOfObjectOnZ(rotationVector.z); // Pseudocode
}
```

The following are helper methods used in the above two methods.

```
public Vector3f rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(float[] m){
    float sy = (float)Math.sqrt(m[6]*m[6] + m[10]*m[10]);

    float x, y, z;

    x = (float)Math.atan2(m[6], m[10]);
    y = (float)Math.atan2(-m[2], sy);
    z = (float)Math.atan2(m[1], m[0]);

    //convert angles from radians to degrees
    float conFactor = (float)(180/Math.PI);
    x *= conFactor;
    y *= conFactor;
    z *= conFactor;

    return new Vector3f(x, y, z);
}

public class QuaternionUtil {
    public static void setRotation(Quat4f q, Vector3f axis, float angle) {
        float d = axis.length();
        assert (d != 0f);
        float s = (float)Math.sin(angle * 0.5f) / d;
        q.set(axis.x * s, axis.y * s, axis.z * s, (float) Math.cos(angle * 0.5f));
    }
}

public class Vector3f{
    public final float length() {
        return (float)Math.sqrt((double)(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z));
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oops, looks like I had forgotten to convert to Radians when using QuaternionUtil.setRotation(). Further, the Quat4f.mul(Quat4f q) method does the opposite of what you'd think. A.mul(B) is B applying a global rotation to A.

Comment: It looks like I can more reliably just store the rotations as quaternions instead of euler angles, so I'll just go for that, instead.